# Deeply nested state in ngxs

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, store, ngxs

I found that we should avoid deep object graphs, and there is an example in the doc https://www.ngxs.io/recipes/style-guide#prefer-1. But I don't understand how to work with this when an item from one state should have a reference to an item in another. Is there a more complete example? How to manage 1..M data, how to load this data properly? Would be nice to see any real examples from github.

For example, how to work with Users-Posts states?